# Need clarification on AnyObject in Swift

Tags: swift, casting, nsobject, typecast-operator

Before I start, I have already read the Swift documentation. I am still trying to comprehend what **AnyObject** actually is. Is it a base class for all objects/classes in Swift, as **NSObject** is in Objective C?

If I create an array of type **[AnyObject]** and populate it with **Movie** class instances, that would mean that **AnyObject** is a base class of the **Movie** class right?

```
let someObjects: [AnyObject] = [
    Movie(name: "2001: A Space Odyssey", director: "Stanley Kubrick"),
    Movie(name: "Moon", director: "Duncan Jones"),
    Movie(name: "Alien", director: "Ridley Scott")
]
```

This should be true or else you wouldn't be able to *downcast* with the type casting operator (**as!**) right?

```
for object in someObjects {
    let movie = object as! Movie
    println("Movie: '\(movie.name)', dir. \(movie.director)")
}
```

The Swift documentation states:

> AnyObject can represent an instance of any class type.

So...represent it in the sense that AnyObject is a base class instance?

I am new to Swift so please have patience :)

Comment: @vacawama already gave a good answer as to what AnyObject is. (voted.) It's a protocol for all class-type objects. In swift, a protocol is a type, so AnyObject means "any object that conforms to this protocol".  I want to mention what it's NOT. It is not a base class. Unlike other OO languages like Objective-C, Swift does not have a common base class for all objects. Instead, all class objects conform to the AnyObject protocol.

Comment: @DuncanC So you are saying that all class objects automatically conform to the AnyObject protocol?

Comment: Yes, all class objects conform to the AnyObject protocol.  So all instances can be assigned to an AnyObject variable, and all class instances can be placed in an `[AnyObject]` array.  You can't extend the `AnyObject` protocol, so in that respect, it doesn't act like a base class.

Comment: @vacawama Ahh. Thank you! That explains it all! I wish they would have put that in the documentation. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AnyObject` is a protocol.  If you type it in a Playground and command click on it the following pops up:

```
/// The protocol to which all classes implicitly conform.
///
/// When used as a concrete type, all known `@objc` methods and
/// properties are available, as implicitly-unwrapped-optional methods
/// and properties respectively, on each instance of `AnyObject`.  For
/// example:
///
/// .. parsed-literal:
///
///   class C {
///     @objc func getCValue() -> Int { return 42 }
///   }
///
///   // If x has a method @objc getValue()->Int, call it and
///   // return the result.  Otherwise, return nil.
///   func getCValue1(x: AnyObject) -> Int? {
///     if let f: ()->Int = **x.getCValue** {
///       return f()
///     }
///     return nil
///   }
///
///   // A more idiomatic implementation using "optional chaining"
///   func getCValue2(x: AnyObject) -> Int? {
///     return **x.getCValue?()**
///   }
///
///   // An implementation that assumes the required method is present
///   func getCValue3(x: AnyObject) -> **Int** {
///     return **x.getCValue()** // x.getCValue is implicitly unwrapped.
///   }
///
/// See also: `AnyClass`
@objc protocol AnyObject {
}
```